# Call the function from one page to another page after self href

Tags: javascript

I want to after click the link of page1, page 2 will be displayed and page 2 will then run the function of its page: `function() {$('a.poin1').trigger("click");`

I have searched many related topics and try to write the code as below but it didn't work.

I will be very appreciated if any one could help. Thanks so much.

```
<a target="_self" href="page2.html" onclick="MyFunction();>
link to page 2
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function MyFunction(){
function() {$('a.poin1').trigger("click");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you really think it is possible? What would prevent from opening your banking account page and sending money somewhere (in case it was possible)?

Comment: Is this jQuery? If so use AJAX to load the page instead of navigating to it.

Comment: zerkms a +1 for that comment cool

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: and if it's not jquery? AJAX request can be sent (BREAKING NEWS) even without jquery

Comment: @zerkms the code looks like jQuery just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are learning hmtl, javascript and some other code right now. It's not enough to copy/paste and hope everything works as you think it should work.

When you skip from page1 to page2 everything is lost. None will remember any function for you.

What you can do, instead, is passing a parameter to the page2. Doing so the page will understand it needs to run some function declared inside it.

Maybe you will need a form to pass hidden values from page1 to page2. Maybe a "get" param is enough. Maybe some php code or whatelse to do what you are trying to do is needed here.

Just try, learn, and break all the keyboards you need :)

Comment: Thanks Gianps. Any idea of function can be sent by a form and execute it?

Comment: @GalaxyLam internet is full of examples. :)